# .NET Regex - really simple regular expression provides false result

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio

Please look at this screenshot grabbed from Visual Studio:

[image: visual studio screenshot]

The expression is really simple, a character range between A and Z, however the second call fails and the third does not. Do I do something wrong, or is this a glitch?

```
Visual Studio version: 14.0.25425.01 Update 3

.NET version: 4.6.01038
```

If you want to give a try, paste-able code snippets:

VB.Net:

```
?Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "A") & vbcrlf & Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "B") & vbcrlf & Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "A-Z")
```

c# Interactive:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "A") + " " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "B") + " " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("[A-Z]", "A-Z")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your arguments are backwards.  Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx:

Regex.IsMatch Method (String, String)

```
public static bool IsMatch(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```